# Why Nodejs sequelize OneToOne same as OneToMany?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sequelize.js

I have Created Two tables That has OneToOne relationship
Parent Table "user" and child table "userinfo"

but I can create as many childs I want that has the same foreignKeys,it doesnt respond any error

What should i do to stop it

here is what i haave tried:

models/index.js

```
//...configs

db.users = require("./Users")(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.userinfo = require("./UserInfo")(sequelize, DataTypes);

db.users.hasOne(db.userinfo);
db.userinfo.belongsTo(db.users, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: "userId",
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've set up a foreign key, you need to also enforce unique constraints. To enforce a unique constraint on the `userId` foreign key in the `userinfo` table, do this:

```js
db.users.hasOne(db.userinfo);
db.userinfo.belongsTo(db.users, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: "userId",
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    unique: true  // enforce unique constraint
  }
});
```

By setting `unique: true`, you ensure that each user in the "user" table can only have one associated record.

Comment: So it means i am cheking it manually i can use has Many too in the same way